# Public class outside a jar file containing multiple packages

Tags: java, jar, package, public

So, I have a Java project containing several packages (like `com.myapp.`a , `com.myapp.b`, `com.myapp.c`) for better readability and I want to build a jar to use as a library in another project.

But I just want to expose only some classes and interfaces from this jar. The problem is that if I don't declare these classes public then they can't be seen inside the jar file between the packages (for example I have a class `A` in `com.myapp.a` package that is used in `com.myapp.b` package).

So how can I expose just what I want outside of the jar when I have multiple packages defined inside?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Java does not address this problem directly.

[OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage) adresses this problem by explicitly defining the exported package list.
Also hopefully this will be addressed with the [Java 8](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=337) Modularity system as well.

So one option is to use [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage), but this option does not work if the jar file is used directly rather than as an [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage) bundle.

Another option is to use code obfuscation (like [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)), to obfuscate the packages you do not want  to expose.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse "solved" this problem by making all classes available, but classes that were not intended to be used by clients were placed in packages whose name contains "internal".  For example, that might mean that you have packages named "com.myapp.b" and "com.myapp.internal.b".  It's made clear to users of the classes that internal classes are not guaranteed to be upwardly compatible or even present in later releases.